# postgres sql statement error: relation doesnt exist

Tags: postgresql

Really struggling to create a table with simple sql on my postgres database cant understand the error im getting. pic attached.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.charters (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('charters_id_seq'::regclass),
    length numeric,
    beam numeric,
    height numeric,
    passengers integer,
    berths integer,
    description text,
    "year" integer,
    power integer,
    price numeric,
    model character varying,
    skipper boolean,
    fuel_included boolean,
    gps boolean,
    shower boolean,
    main_img character varying,
    title character varying,
    created_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    "location" character varying,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

[image]

Comment: Make that line ` id serial NOT NULL DEFAULT` per [Serial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) or `integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` per [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). Then the sequence is created for you and owned by the column.

Answer (score 2):

Did you create a sequence charters_id_seq? Looks like the database can't find it. Using an IDENTITY might be easier, you don't have to create the sequence yourself:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.charters (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    length numeric,
    beam numeric,
    height numeric,
    passengers integer,
    berths integer,
    description text,
    "year" integer,
    power integer,
    price numeric,
    model character varying,
    skipper boolean,
    fuel_included boolean,
    gps boolean,
    shower boolean,
    main_img character varying,
    title character varying,
    created_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    "location" character varying
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a sequence `charters_id_seq` :

Exemple :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE charters_id_seq START 101;
```

Then :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.charters (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('charters_id_seq'::regclass),
    length numeric,
    beam numeric,
    height numeric,
    passengers integer,
    berths integer,
    description text,
    "year" integer,
    power integer,
    price numeric,
    model character varying,
    skipper boolean,
    fuel_included boolean,
    gps boolean,
    shower boolean,
    main_img character varying,
    title character varying,
    created_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    "location" character varying,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

To associate the sequence to the specific table column, such that if that column (or its whole table) is dropped, the sequence will be automatically dropped as well, then use this :

```
ALTER SEQUENCE charters_id_seq OWNED BY public.charters.id ;
```

This will avoid permissions issues as well

Comment: You might get into trouble with permissions for the sequence and there is no relation between the sequence and the table. Use at least OWNED BY to create the relation between the two